# Как узнать загрузился ли браузре...?

Tags: vb.net

Как узнать загрузился ли браузре елси известно только положения браузера то есть Он находиться на вкладке

Comment: `   щито) `

Comment: Надо узнать загрузился ли браузер имя его не известно

Comment: Браузер создается при загрузки формы

Comment: ![У нас тут своя атмосфера][1]

Извините, навеяло.

  [1]: http://cs5908.userapi.com/v5908654/892/jmkjxkP7Vhw.jpg

Comment: О, да! На этой картинке я познакомился с Вонни))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно посмотрел в хрустальный шар, то нужно найти на форме компонент `WebBrowser` (про который ничего кроме того, что он где-то есть неизвестно) и проверить его состояние.

Тогда, я подозреваю, как-то так:

```
Private Sub FoundWebBrowser(ByVal ctl As WebBrowser)
    If ctl.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        ' Как-то так.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FindAllWebBrowsers(ByVal ctl As Control)
    If TypeOf ctl Is WebBrowser Then
        FoundWebBrowser(ctl)
    End If

    If ctl.HasChildren Then
        For Each c As Control In ctl.Controls
            EnumControls(c)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

И в нужном месте вызвать `FindAllWebBrowsers`, передав ей форму.

Comment: Этих браузеров может быть много

Comment: Ну так найдет все, на каждый вызовет функцию. В код посмотрите.